# Can you reach 2020?

Tags: formation-of-numbers

Start with the numbers 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 in that order and use the four common operations (+ − × ÷) and number concatenation (ie, you may write 123 concatenating 1, 2, 3) to obtain 2020.

Some clarifications:

- All the ten numbers must be used, in that order, without repetitions.
- Unary - is allowed; inserting decimal point is also allowed.
- Number 10 cannot be split as 1 0; it can of course be concatenated with 9 to obtain 910.
- Concatenation may only be applied to literal digits.
- Exponentiation is not allowed, even though it is written without any explicit operators.

Comment: There seem to be many many solutions to this question. It might be worth considering some tighter restrictions.

Comment: In particular you should disallow concatenation

Comment: I am not sure that there is a solution without concatenation.

Comment: Can we use parentheses ?

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way to do it if we disallow concatenation, division, unary and decimals

> $(((1-(2\times 3)+4+(5\times 6)) \times 7) +8 - 9) \times 10 = 2020$

although there will be many others.

Answer (score 2):

My two cents

> (12*34)*5+6*7-8*9+10 = 2020

Comment: Those brackets are not needed. :)

Comment: @sudhackar indeed, but it just helps me visually

Answer (score 2):

Here's some

> 12*34*5-6-7-8-9+10 
>  123+45*6*7+8+9-10 
>  12+34*5*6+78+910 
>  1*2*34*5*6+7-8-9-10 
>  1*23*45+67+8+910

Answer (score 0):

> $((1+2) \div 3+45+67+89) \times 10 = 2020$